# why should I not use MVC Jsonresult instead of apicontroller get method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-apicontroller, jsonresult

I have developed an application which was MVC application. It has a requirement that the application will return json data for one get request.
So I have added apicontroller and created a get method to return json data.

So far so good. but then I thought, is it really needed to add apicontroller to create just one get method.

I started exploring and googling what is the difference other than content negotiation. Got lots of answers and articles but non of them were satisfactory.

So here is the actual confusion, why can't I just create a method in the MVC controller with JsonResponse and return the json data(Which I know only is need for my requirement, but other application on different domain will consume it).

Can anyone convince me why should I use apicontroller instead of MVC JsonResponse for my requirement or should I not be using apicontroller at all.

apology if there is any mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right the question is Can we use MVC action to serve `json` content answer is *yes*! Is it okay to use `Json Result`? answer is *It depends where do you want to consume it*

Say I am an in a Web Environment where I have no need for the APIs (that means I am not going to serve my data to multiple clients) If that's the scenario where only your View is going to consume data returned from your Action Method you are good to go. An Action returning a `Json Result` is basically an Action Result and that's what it is made for.

but If you are in a REST scenario and you need your backend to serve your *data* to the client *de facto standard* is to use an independent Web API for that.

Controllers' main responsibility *should be* to work as an intermediary between your View and Model and whatever *service layer* you want to bring inside it. on the other hand, Web APIs are data-driven there *only* purpose is to serve data (use them if you need them)

Web APIs are good cause they give you the flexibility of serving the data to possibly *any client* that might need it. That's what I would pick if I am starting from scratch but if I only need to serve data to one client Controller Action methods will be way to go.

Hope this helps.